# access denied when executing a node.js based aws lambda function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am working on a function based on ytdl module for node.js. Actually, i just want to downloqd a youtube video.
When I test my function, I got this error :

```
2017-12-16T17:25:48.627Z 27dbca8d-e286-11e7-9f17-851e6c66e221 Error: spawn EACCES
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
at exports.spawn (child_process.js:378:9)
at exports.execFile (child_process.js:143:15)
at call (/var/task/node_modules/youtube-dl/lib/youtube-dl.js:163:5)
at Function.getInfo (/var/task/node_modules/youtube-dl/lib/youtube-dl.js:285:5)
at module.exports (/var/task/node_modules/youtube-dl/lib/youtube-dl.js:107:10)
at exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:6:14)
```

after some googling requests, I found that it is related to access problem. However, my code have no special operations that needs access permission. 
Could you help please

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var ytdl = require('./node_modules/youtube-dl');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var video = ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AW8OOp2undg',
            // Optional arguments passed to youtube-dl.
            ['-o', '/tmp/test.mp4']);


        var size = 0;
        video.on('info', function(info) {
            'use strict';
            size = info.size;

            console.log('Got video info');
            var file = path.join(__dirname, info._filename);
            video.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(file));

        });

        var pos = 0;
        video.on('data', function data(chunk) {
            'use strict';
            pos += chunk.length;

            // `size` should not be 0 here.
            if (size) {
                var percent = (pos / size * 100).toFixed(2);
                process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
                process.stdout.clearLine(1);
                process.stdout.write(percent + '%');
            }
        });

        video.on('end', function end() {
            'use strict';
            console.log('\nDone');
        });


callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda');

};
```

Comment: Check if you have set correct permissions for the folder `/tmp/`. Also: You don't have to write `require('./node_modules/youtube-dl')`. Just`require('youtube-dl')` is enough since it will search in the `node_modules` folder first anyway.

Comment: Thank you. Could you give a permission sample fot /tmp.

Comment: `sudo chmod -R a+rwx /tmp/`  -  however keep in mind, this will make the folder read and writable for anyone. Let me know if that worked. I add it as an answer then.

Comment: I have never executed a command on aws lambda. In fact i am a newbie.

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the server? I never used aws lambda.

Comment: I think that we cannot ssh aws lambda

Comment: *"my code have no special operations that needs access permission"*  You are hitting `EACCES`, which means the operating system is throwing an error (code 13) because you lack a permission -- possibly to execute a binary that lacks the `x` execute bit.

Answer (score 1):

node-ytdl use precompiled binaries so you should deploy your lambda from the same OS/arch as the target.

Or use the pure javascript module :

> If you're only interested in downloading only from youtube, you should consider using pure Javascript youtube downloading module. => https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl

source : https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-dl

Answer (score 0):

just change permission of youtube-dl:

```
chmod +x youtube-dl
```